# How do you search for a certain thing in a text file in python?

Tags: python, text-files

I have a text file:

```
E5341,21/09/2015,C102,440,E,0
E5342,21/09/2015,C103,290,A,290
E5343,21/09/2015,C104,730,N,0
E5344,22/09/2015,C105,180,A,180
E5345,22/09/2015,C106,815,A,400
E5346,23/09/2015,C107,970,N,0
E5347,23/09/2015,C108,1050,E,0
E5348,23/09/2015,C109,370,A,200
E5349,25/09/2015,C110,480,A,250
E5350,25/09/2015,C111,330,A,330
E5351,25/09/2015,C112,1750,E,0
E5352,28/09/2015,C113,1500,N,0
E5353,28/09/2015,C114,272,A,200
E5354,29/09/2015,C115,560,E,0
E5355,29/09/2015,C116,530,A,450
E5356,29/09/2015,C117,860,E,0
E5357,29/09/2015,C118,650,E,0
E5358,29/09/2015,C119,380,A,380
E5359,29/09/2015,C120,980,N,0
E5360,30/09/2015,C121,1375,E,0
E5361,01/10/2015,C122,374,A,374
```

The E stands for the estimate number

The date following the estimate number is the estimated date

The C stands for the customer number

The number following the customer number is the final total in £

The letter after the final total tells you if the job was accepted(A) or not accepted (N) or the job was just an estimate (E)

The number after the status^ is the total amount already paid in £

I want to find out how if I enter one of the estimate numbers in python can I print out the date or work out the outstanding payments and find out what status the job is.

I've tried to research this but I don't understand it, I would really appreciate any help towards this.

The expected outcome if i put in the estimate number of 5353 is meant to show the date which would be 28/09/2015 for that example

Comment: There are a ton of ways to go about this, but you'll have to show some effort on your end. You didn't even show an attempt or what you've tried so far.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Share your attempts with us and what problems you faced.

Comment: i will find my attempts and post them on here

Comment: post the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea in Python 2 (note I have not tested this, but it should be close or work as is):

```
search = '5356' # supply this as your search
search = 'E'+search
fh = open('textfile.txt')
for line in fh:
    elements = line.split(',')
    if len(elements) == 6:
        if elements[0] == search:
            print 'For Estimate #'+search
            print 'date:'+elements[1]
            print 'cust:'+elements[2]
            print 'totl:'+elements[3]
            print 'stat:'+elements[4]
            print 'paid:'+elements[5]
fh.close()
```

Now... go look up each statement in that example in the Python 2 documentation and see what the various items in it do. That'll give you a little kickstart towards learning the language, if you are ever going to do any more in it.

Keep in mind that failure is possible: What if the text file name is wrong, for instance, and the file open fails? You'll want to look at the `try` and `except` Python language elements.

Everyone needs to start somewhere, which is why I didn't give you a snarky "show your work" answer. So here's your start. Go forth and learn. :)

Comment: thank you very much! this has really helped a lot as I didnt know where to start, i will try it out for myself and try to figure out in further detail what various of the terminology means

Comment: i tried this method and looked into it but everytime i try this keeps happening

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Jayden/Desktop/PYTHON/task3A test.py", line 13, in <module>
    print("the customer ID is: ")+elements[2]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: im not sure what it means

Comment: Using your test file (above) and the code as provided, it works fine here. Perhaps you're not using Python 2, but Python 3? Python 3 and Python 2 are not compatible with each other. Suggestion: change each of the `+elements[n]` statements to read `+str(elements[n])` and see what happens.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what happened. You are using Python3, which is **not** the same as Python2; the print statement is different there, `print('string')` instead of `print 'string'`;  
  
You've converted the statement incorrectly: it should read:  
  
 `print('the customer ID is:'+elements[2])`
  
Not:  
  
`print('the customer ID is:')+elements[2]`

But I suggest you use `print('the customer ID is:'+str(elements[2]))`